# Choosing Null Hypothesis

Tags: hypothesis-testing, inference

I am studying Hypothesis Testing, I see that my instructor used to put the equal sign in the null hypothesis for all examples, this makes me confused about  how to choose the null and the alternative hypothesis. What is the general rule to follow in such a case.

For example, for " At least 70% of next year's alumni will find a job.",
My instructor write  H0: p=0.7 and  H1(alternative): p>0.7.

Can anyone clarify this for me?

Comment: Your instructor made a mistake, the alternative hypothesis is the complement of the null, so in your case should be `p!=0.7` (to either side).

Comment: @user2974951 not necessarily, it is possible to do a one-sided hypothesis test. And indeed that might be what is suggested by the language "at least" in the problem statement.

Comment: Right, the null should be `p<=0.7` and the alternative is correct.